# same subdomains with 2 different domains

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns, subdomain, wildcard

I have 2 domains. say, domain1.com and domain2.com.
domain1.com has many sub-domains. say, sub1.domain1.com, sub2.domain1.com and so on...

I need to map domain2.com in such a way that its redirected from *.domain2.com/? to *.domain1.com/?

do i need to use htaccess? if yes, how?

-thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes using .htaccess file will definitely make it easy for you. Can you try this in you .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*\.?)domain2\.com$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://%1domain1.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

A URL of the form sub1.domain2.com/foo will be redirected to sub1.domain1.com/foo and this will send http status code=301 with the new URL to browser.

Comment: @Manish Chiniwalar: Thanks for pointing out. I have modified my answer, please check.

Comment: thanks for the help :)
But i'm not sure why, even with the mod rewrite enabled, its not working :(

Comment: @Manish Chiniwalar: I made a very minor modification, can you pls try again. If it still doesn't work can you try commenting out `RewriteCond` part and see if you are getting infinite redirects in your browser (just for testing).